# Subset of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a subset of my 'monthstest' dataframe that only includes results from the year 2018.

[image]

When I try the following I get an error,

[image]

I have tried changing the data type from an object to a string using the following but it stays as an object.

[image]

Any ideas what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do is:

```
monthstest[monthstest["Months"].str.contains("18-")]
```

Answer (score 0):

From your line:

```
monthstest[monthstest.str.contains('-18')]
# the monthstest inside [] is the entire dataframe, which contains fields other than 'Months', so comparing '-18' against one row of record is not well-defined.
```

So, you may try to consider the 'Month' column only:

```
monthstest[monthstest['Month'.str.contains('18-')]]   # i think it is '18-'?
```

another way to do it (don't know if its more efficient though):

```
monthstest[ ['18-' in m for m in monthstest['Month']] ]
```